# Java build List from values of multiple Maps in a particular order

Tags: java, algorithm

Suppose you have a List of Integers in a meaningful order (List1).

You also have two Map's where the Integer keys are a subset of List1. There is no overlap between the two Maps, but between them both it may be possible that List1 is a proper superset of the set of both of their keySets (i.e., there are some Integers in List1 missing from both Maps).

How can you build a new List of Objects from the two Maps in which the Objects appear in the order that their Integer key appears in List1?

Comment: Do you want `list2` to contain keys or values from the maps?

Comment: What about the elements missing on List1, do you want them on the resulting list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this fairly simply with a loop:

```
Map map1;
Map map2;
List list2;
// iterate through all of the possible keys in order
for(Object possibleKey: List1) {
    // If the possible ke is a key in one of the maps,
    // add it to your new list.  This will preserve order.
    if(map1.containsKey(possibleKey))
        list2.add(map1.get(possibleKey));
    else if (map2.containsKey(possibleKey))
        list2.add(map2.get(possibleKey));
}
```

The above code is simplified, but you should get the general idea.

Comment: Oops, OP wants values, not keys

Comment: @Sean, yup.  Saw that.  Will fix.

Comment: OK, now your solution is pretty much identical to jzd's

Comment: @Sean, yup.  I believe it is identical actually.  (But mine has code)

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a list for your objects.
2. Loop through the List and check in both maps for an Object.
3. Which ever map has a match add that object to your new list.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<MyObj> l = new ArrayList<MyObj>();
for(Integer i: list1)
   MyObj o = (map1.containsKey(i))?map1.get(i):map2.get(i);
   if(o!=null)
     l.add(o);
```

---

Updated with containsKey, seems fancy.

Answer (score 0):

### Use a [`SortedMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html):

The nice thing about a SortedMap is that all of it's collection views are both a) sorted and 
b) backed by the map, which makes it very easy to restrict the map values to those in the list and retrieve the values in the correct order:

```
// create a SortedMap
SortedMap<Integer,Object> sortedMap = new TreeMap<Integer, Object>();
// add the entries of the first map
sortedMap.putAll(map1);
// add the entries of the second map
// (all entries are now sorted by key)
sortedMap.putAll(map2);
// now remove all entries that are not in List1
sortedMap.keySet().retainAll(list1);
// and here's your list of the values, sorted by key
List<Object> arrayList = new ArrayList<Object>(sortedMap.values());
```

### Reference:

> [`SortedMap.keySet()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html#keySet%28%29): Returns a Set
>   view of the keys contained in this
>   map. The set's iterator returns the
>   keys in ascending order. The set is
>   backed by the map, so changes to the
>   map are reflected in the set, **and
>   vice-versa**. [...] The set supports
>   element removal, which removes the
>   corresponding mapping from the map,
>   via the [...] **retainAll**, and clear
>   operations.
>
> [`Set.retainAll()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29): Retains only the
>   elements in this set that are
>   contained in the specified collection
>   (optional operation). In other words,
>   **removes from this set all of its
>   elements that are not contained in the
>   specified collection**.
>
> [`SortedMap.values()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html#values%28%29): Returns a `Collection` view of the
>   values contained in this map. The
>   collection's iterator returns the
>   values **in ascending order of the
>   corresponding keys**. The collection is
>   backed by the map, so changes to the
>   map are reflected in the collection,
>   and vice-versa.